# How to set the FlagStatus on the "Sent" copy of a message?

Tags: vba, outlook

Essentially I want to run the following code.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If InStr(Item.Body, "XYZ") > 0 Then
        mailItem.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
        mailItem.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

This gives me two problems. Firstly Outlook won't let me set the `FlagStatus` in this event, so I have to set `FlagRequest` to "Complete".

Maybe I can live with this. Secondly, and more importantly, this flag is set in the copy of the message that goes to the recipients but is not set in the copy of the message that I keep.

I need this flag set for me, not the recipient of the message. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Outlook won't let me set the FlagStatus in this even"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, I get Run-time error 440, "The object does not support this method." Standard, "you can set this property in this event." message. Probably because this is fired before the message is sent. Ideally, I want to get at the message after it has been sent so that I know I'm dealing with the message in my sent items folder, not the message that is going out.

Comment: Did you mean to set FlagStatus to olFlagComplete on the original message to which the user replies?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder.

In the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Private WithEvents sentFolItms As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set sentFolItms = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub sentFolItms_ItemAdd(ByVal sMail As Object)
    If InStr(sMail.Body, "XYZ") > 0 Then
        sMail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
        sMail.Save
    End If
End Sub
```